# Get the description of a status code in Python Requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I would like to be able to enter a server response code and have Requests tell me what the code means. For example, code 200 --> ok

I found a link to the [source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py) which shows the dictionary structure of the codes and descriptions. I see that Requests will return a response code for a given description:

```
print requests.codes.processing  # returns 102
print requests.codes.ok          # returns 200
print requests.codes.not_found   # returns 404
```

But not the other way around:

```
print requests.codes[200]        # returns None
print requests.codes.viewkeys()  # returns dict_keys([])
print requests.codes.keys()      # returns []
```

I thought this would be a routine task, but cannot seem to find an answer to this in online searching, or in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Alternatively, in case of Python 2.x, you can use [`httplib.responses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.responses):

```
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.responses[200]
'OK'
>>> httplib.responses[404]
'Not Found'
```

In Python 3.x, use [`http` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.responses):

```
In [1]: from http.client import responses

In [2]: responses[200]
Out[2]: 'OK'

In [3]: responses[404]
Out[3]: 'Not Found'
```

Comment: I preferred to stay within `Requests`, but this is a useful alternative; thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Roberto `httplib` is a stock module, so there's nothing encumbered here.

Comment: httplib is a Python 2.7 thing; from 3.5 there's `http.HTTPStatus`. Where is it in 3.4?

Comment: @user508402 did you mean to use `from http.client import responses` for the mapping between status code and messages? (I've also updated the answer and included the 3.x version) Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, there they are. With that list it is easy to make my own duck typed HTTPStatus. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

One possibility:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.status_codes._codes[200]
('ok', 'okay', 'all_ok', 'all_okay', 'all_good', '\\o/', '\xe2\x9c\x93')
```

The first value in the tuple is used as the conventional code key.

Comment: `requests.status_codes._codes` is an implementation detail you shouldn't be touching. Note the don't-touch-me underscore on `_codes`. Such implementation details are subject to change or removal without notice.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem before and found the
answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167579/6532920)

Basically:

- `responsedata.status_code` - gives you the integer status code
- `responsedata.reason` - gives the text/string representation of the status code

Comment: This has to be comment rather than answering to the questions

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. The current answer with most votes is to use `httplib`. But the `requests` library already provides (within itself) the functionality to decipher the meaning (or string description) of the response code. You don't have to go elsewhere for this.

Comment: I don't think reason exists in earlier versions of responses.

Comment: @JonathanRoberts how early are we talking here?  It was available in requests version 2.0 (committed september 2013) https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/4f463e897afb15db253994829af24928cf4f4535/requests/models.py#L518

Comment: As far as I know, the `Response.reason` is provided server-side.  This might be useful or dangerous depending on your intended use case.

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.x this will work

```py
>>> from http import HTTPStatus
>>> HTTPStatus(200).phrase
'OK'
```

Answer (score -1):

> requests.status_codes.codes.OK

works nicely and makes it more readable in my application code

Notice that in [source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py): the requests.status_codes.codes is of type [LookupDict](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/structures.py#L102) which overrides method **getitem**

You could see all the supported keys with - `dir(requests.status_codes.codes)`

### When using in combination with FLASK:

i like use following enum from flask-api plugin
`from flask_api import status` where i get more descriptive version of HTTP status codes as in -

> status.HTTP_200_OK

Comment: You've described how to get the numerical value from the name. The question was about how to get the text description from the numerical value - the reverse operation.