# How to extract the HTTP error text from a requests response?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
tries = 10
for n in range(tries):
    try:
        ....
        responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
        responsedata.raise_for_status()
        ..
        if .... : 
            break   #exit loop condition

    except (ChunkedEncodingError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as e:
        print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Msg: {3}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, sys.exc_info()[0]))
        if n == tries - 1:
           raise e  # exit the process
```

The prints I see are:

```
page #53 run #0 failed. Returned status code 502. Msg: <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>. Retry.
page #1 run #1 failed. Returned status code 500. Msg: <class 'requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError'>. Retry.
```

While this is Ok it doesn't give me actual information about the problem. The message just tell me the exception title.

If I print the: `responsedata.text` when exception happens I see:

```
 Returned status code 502. Message is: ...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
```

This is a giant message most of it is garbage but it also says: `502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.`
can I access this message and also print it to my log?

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm aware of that but the API can raise more types or errors, some can be unique. I'm asking how to access the message using request package

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can access the response's status code using `responsedata.status_code` and its textual description via `responsedata.reason` (see more in http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/)

Comment: Nice but it contains a diffrent message. For example it says: `Bad Gateway` instead of `Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.`

Comment: That message is in the response's title, added by the webserver. In other words, it's specific to this URL you're accessing, not to any webserver (as my answer). If you want to extract it, you'll need to parse the HTML and extract its `title` tag. You can see how on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812470/how-to-get-page-title-in-requests.

Comment: Adding to my comment, it seems this message is just the default message IIS adds for status code 500. It doesn't add more information, it's just more verbose. Considering that extracting it would involve parsing the HTML, I'd suggest just logging the HTTP Error code, as it has the same information. If you want to extract it anyway, the solution is linked in my previous comment.

Comment: When raised with raise_for_status(), e.reason contains a default message that's put there by the requests library, [source code for requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/3.0/requests/models.py#L1024). user1898153's answer gets to the actual response from the exception handler.

Answer (score 13):

If your endpoint returns a detailed, application-specific error message in the response body, you can make use of the fact that a requests `HTTPError` retains a reference to the `Response` that caused it to be raised:

```
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

try:
    # Some code that makes requests
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.response.text)
```

Comment: This is gold.Thank you

Comment: For me, exceptions handle errors at code side and can't handle API response. Eg: with a bad route, no Exception is raised , just an error message in the response `try:
        req = requests.post(endpoint, headers=head,
                            data=json.dumps(payload))
        print(f'{req.text} - OK')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'{req.text} -  KO {e}')`. I this case, not exception. The `TRY`is ok and the`req.text`only shows `bad route`