# Convert HTTP response code to text message with Python standard package

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, http-headers

This question is about the [HTTP Response Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

In my python application I want to present the user the text related to such a code. e.g. `404` would be `Not Found`.

I checked the python docs but couldn't found a package which give me the text/string for the codes. Isn't there really nothing like this in the python libraries?

A workaround would be to use an external source. E.g. the [official CSV file](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml#http-status-codes-1) from the IANA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718557/get-the-description-of-a-status-code-in-python-requests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Ohad for the hint. With Python3.x I see two nice ways.

### 1 - Using `requests` module

```
>>> from requests import status_codes
>>> mycode = 404
>>> status_codes._codes[mycode][0]
'not_found'
```

### 2 - Using `http.client` module

```
>>> from http.client import responses
>>> responses[404]
'Not Found'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use http standard library in Python3.

`list(http.HTTPStatus)` will give you the complete list.

You can get the `name` and `value` attributes:

```
for x in list(http.HTTPStatus):
    print(str(x.value) + ' : ' + x.name)
```

prints:

```
    100 : CONTINUE
    101 : SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS
    102 : PROCESSING
    200 : OK
    201 : CREATED

.....

    510 : NOT_EXTENDED
    511 : NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED
```